# How to downgrade magento ver 2 from 2.2.2 to 2.1.10?

Tags: magento2

Recently, i upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2 and right now i have a lot of issue so

Can i downgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.1.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of your 2.1.7 database then downgrading Magento and reverting your database to that backup would be the way to go.

If that is not an option because of loss of sales data, I would recommend contacting an agency which can merge your new sales data onto your 'old' 2.1.7 database.